# How to efficiently apply a function to each channel of every pixel in an image (for color conversion)?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement Reinhard's method to use the color distribution of a target image to color normalize a passed in image for a research project. I've gotten the code to work and it outputs correctly but it's pretty slow. It takes about 20 minutes to iterate through 300 images. I'm pretty sure the bottleneck is how I'm handling applying the function to each image. I'm currently iterating through each pixel of the image and applying the functions below to each channel.

[image]

```
def reinhard(target, img):

    #converts image and target from BGR colorspace to l alpha beta
    lAB_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
    lAB_tar = cv2.cvtColor(target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)

    #finds mean and standard deviation for each color channel across the entire image
    (mean, std) = cv2.meanStdDev(lAB_img)
    (mean_tar, std_tar) = cv2.meanStdDev(lAB_tar)

    #iterates over image implementing formula to map color normalized pixels to target image
    for y in range(512):
        for x in range(512):
            lAB_tar[x, y, 0] = (lAB_img[x, y, 0] - mean[0]) / std[0] * std_tar[0] + mean_tar[0]
            lAB_tar[x, y, 1] = (lAB_img[x, y, 1] - mean[1]) / std[1] * std_tar[1] + mean_tar[1]
            lAB_tar[x, y, 2] = (lAB_img[x, y, 2] - mean[2]) / std[2] * std_tar[2] + mean_tar[2]
    mapped = cv2.cvtColor(lAB_tar, cv2.COLOR_Lab2BGR)
    return mapped
```

My supervisor told me that I could try using a matrix to apply the function all at once to improve the runtime but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: A quick look at numpy documentation wouldn't hurt. Use the vectorized operations it provides.

Comment: If it helps, it looks like someone has already done something similar you may be able to adapt (though it looks very custom, for his own lab staining package), source code [here](https://github.com/Peter554/StainTools/blob/master/staintools/reinhard_color_normalizer.py)

Answer (score 3):

The original and the target：

[image]
[image]

Color transfer reuslts using Reinhard'method in `5 ms`:

[image] 
[image]

---

I prefer to implement the formulat in `numpy vectorized operations` other than `python loops`.

```
# implementing the formula
#(Io - mo)/so*st + mt  = Io * (st/so) + mt - mo*(st/so)
ratio = (std_tar/std_ori).reshape(-1)
offset = (mean_tar - mean_ori*std_tar/std_ori).reshape(-1)
lab_tar = cv2.convertScaleAbs(lab_ori*ratio + offset)
```

Here is the code:

```
# 2019/02/19 by knight-金
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/54757659/3547485

import numpy as np
import cv2

def reinhard(target, original):
    # cvtColor: COLOR_BGR2Lab
    lab_tar = cv2.cvtColor(target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
    lab_ori = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)

    # meanStdDev: calculate mean and stadard deviation
    mean_tar, std_tar = cv2.meanStdDev(lab_tar)
    mean_ori, std_ori = cv2.meanStdDev(lab_ori)

    # implementing the formula
    #(Io - mo)/so*st + mt  = Io * (st/so) + mt - mo*(st/so)
    ratio = (std_tar/std_ori).reshape(-1)
    offset = (mean_tar - mean_ori*std_tar/std_ori).reshape(-1)
    lab_tar = cv2.convertScaleAbs(lab_ori*ratio + offset)

    # convert back
    mapped = cv2.cvtColor(lab_tar, cv2.COLOR_Lab2BGR)
    return mapped

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ori = cv2.imread("ori.png")
    tar = cv2.imread("tar.png")

    mapped = reinhard(tar, ori)
    cv2.imwrite("mapped.png", mapped)

    mapped_inv = reinhard(ori, tar)
    cv2.imwrite("mapped_inv.png", mapped)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out after looking at the numpy documentation. I just needed to replace my nested for loop with proper array accessing. It took less than a minute to iterate through all 300 images with this.

```
lAB_tar[:,:,0] = (lAB_img[:,:,0] - mean[0])/std[0] * std_tar[0] + mean_tar[0]
lAB_tar[:,:,1] = (lAB_img[:,:,1] - mean[1])/std[1] * std_tar[1] + mean_tar[1]
lAB_tar[:,:,2] = (lAB_img[:,:,2] - mean[2])/std[2] * std_tar[2] + mean_tar[2]
```

Comment: Do them in parallel and you'll get them all done in 20s  Well done for working it out and sharing it.

Comment: Good work :) Now, I have a feeling you can reduce this to a single line, give it a shot...